# Is it possible to buy content from itunes store via iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, itunes-store

Is it possible to buy content from itunes store via iPhone app? Does apple allows to purchase stuff from iTunes using iTunes API? And is there an ability in the API to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

NO, it's not possible at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy in-app content like additional levels for games or additional books for ebook readers. You can not use an application to buy another app or song from iTunes but I saw many app linking directly to the store.

If you do this your running app will close (or go to the background) and iTunes on your iOS device will open. I guess it is done very simple with just the right kind of hyperlink since desktop applications and websites can do it too.